# Matlab optimization - conditional sum of optimization variable in constraint

Tags: matlab, constraints, linear-programming

I'm trying to solve a *ILP* problem using binary variables in `MATLAB` (bintprog). I need to define a constraint similar as below :

[image: constraint]

I want to sum binary variables `x<sub>i, j</sub>` until one of them equals to `zero` and after that stop this summation. How can I define this constraint in ILP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I read this (somewhat difficult as there is little explanation; I think the question could have been phrased more clearly), this is essentially counting the first `x(k)`'s that are 1. Here I assume `x(i,j)` is mapped to `x(k)` so we have a better defined ordering. The counting can be done using a new binary variable `y(k)`:

```
y(k) = x(k)*y(k-1)   if k>1
y(k) = x(k)          if k=1
y(k) in {0,1}
```

For example:

```
x = [1 1 1 0 1 0]
y = [1 1 1 0 0 0]
```

The nonlinear expression `x(k)*y(k-1)` can easily be linearized (it is a multiplication of two binary variables; see [here](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2008/05/multiplication-of-binary-variables.html); note that with this formulation we can even relax `y(k)` to continuous between 0 and 1). An optimized version can look like:

```
y(k) >= x(k)+y(k-1)-1   if k>1
y(k) = x(k)             if k=1
0 <= y(k) <= 1
```

Now you just can do

```
sum(k, y(k)) <= c
```

This formulation would also allow to say: number of leading 1s should be between c1 and c2.

We can also just write immediately:

```
x(1) + ... + x(c+1) <= c
```

which also forbids more than c leading 1s and is even simpler.

A different problem we see more often (e.g. in generator scheduling) is the condition that we cannot have more than c consecutive `x(k)`'s turned on (i.e. the generator can not be on for more than c consecutive periods: after c periods on, the generator must be turned off for at least 1 period). This means we don't allow sequences of more than c 1's.

Comment: @fereshte Out of interest, what is the background of this constraint?

Comment: I used this constraint in a specific network for minimizing energy consumption.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a non-typical MIP-constraint in my opinion. Here is my attempt in formulating this:

[image]

You have to think about:

- the necessity of handling Case B (dependent on your objective and other constraints) and the downfalls of the bigM-approach [nice read](http://orinanobworld.blogspot.de/2011/07/perils-of-big-m.html)
- how to implement the product of two binary-variables (which is easy; see [here](http://orinanobworld.blogspot.de/2010/10/binary-variables-and-quadratic-terms.html))

**EDIT**

At the cost of the double amount of binary-auxiliary variables, it is also possible to formulate this without bigM-constants.

Sketch:

- Instead of using a one-sided *implication* to set the indicators, use *equality* == *both-implications* -> no aux-var is free; all are 0 or 1 depending on x(z) only
- Now build a second layer of binary-aux variables (b_i) with the following idea: `b_i >= smallConst * b_i-1 + smallConst * a_i` (smallConst in (0, 0.5]; should not be close 0 )
- Use b-vector for your final sum-constraint (like describes above; but not using a-vector anymore!)